# How can I fix my report function?

Tags: python, pycharm

My load library works well and my report author counts works in Python but when I upload it to an automatic evaluation it says

> =ERROR: File report.txt contains 0 lines, but shall contain 1 lines.

```
def load_library(f):

    with open(f,'rt') as x:
        return dict(map(str.strip, line.split("|")) for line in x)  

def count_authors(file_name):
         invert = {}
         for k, v in load_library(file_name).items():
            invert[v] = invert.get(v, 0) + 1
         return invert


def write_authors_counts(counts, file_name):
        with open(file_name, 'w') as fobj:
            for name, count in counts.items():
                fobj.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count))


def report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath):
        counts = count_authors(lib_fpath)
        write_authors_counts(counts, rep_filepath)
```

Report Author Counts

```
  In module library.py, create function report_author_counts(lib_fpath, rep_filepath) which shall compute the number of books of each author and the total number of books, and shall store this information in another text file.

    Inputs:
    Path to a library text file (containing records for individual books).
    Path to report text file that shall be created by this function.
    Outputs: None
    Assuming the file books.txt has the same contents as above, running the function like this:

    >>> report_author_counts('books.txt', 'report.txt')
    shall create a new text file report.txt with the following contents:

    Clarke, Arthur C.: 2
    Herbert, Frank: 2
    Capek, Karel: 1
    Asimov, Isaac: 3
    TOTAL BOOKS: 8
    The order of the lines is irrelevant. Do not forget the TOTAL BOOKS line! If the input file is empty, the output file shall contain just the line TOTAL BOOKS: 0.

    Suggestion: There are basically 2 ways how to implement this function. You can either

    use the 2 above functions to load the library, transform it using index_by_author() and then easilly iterate over the dictionary, or
    you can work directly with the source text file, extract the author names, and count their occurences.
    Both options are possible, provided the function will accept the specified arguments and will produce the right file contents. The choice is up to you.
```

Comment: One issue, the report.txt output needs to have a "TOTAL BOOKS: #" line.  I don't see that in your code.  Is it possible that that is what is tricking it up?

Comment: yes exactly thats why it was not working... @Rob-davis fixed it below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that you are failing the base case of what happens when you are given an empty library text.  The output should have a single line "TOTAL BOOKS: 0" but you don't have that in your code.

Update your code with the following:

```
def write_authors_counts(counts, file_name):
    tot_books = 0 # new line
    with open(file_name, 'w') as fobj:
        for name, count in counts.items():
            fobj.write('{}: {}\n'.format(name, count))
            tot_books += int(count)  # new line
        fobj.write('TOTAL BOOKS: ' + str(tot_books)) # new line
```